# Get all labels in TFS 2010

Tags: tf-cli

Is it possible to get all the labels recursively across nested folders?

When doing something like:

```
tf history *  /recursive
```

In the labels tab I see

> "The parameter filterItem may not contain wildcards"

I've tried various different options, but no luck and I can't find a reference to doing labels recursively in msdn.

EDIT:
To elaborate with the background to my question, we use labels to mark hotfix releases. So a release is a branch, but a hotfix is a label. I want to get all the hotfix labels across the project.

Answer (score 0):

Change to the directory you are interested in and do `tf.exe labels` and this will show you all labels where the directory is included in. You can than get more detailed information about one label by using `tf.exe /format:detailed labelname`.

Comment: Thanks @Mike but I'm looking to find all labels for a solution no matter what directory.

Comment: Do you mean one specific .sln file or all occurances of that file and the connected labels? Or every label that is used inside a TeamProject?

Comment: Good question Mike, I've edited the question text to include the context.

Comment: If you just want to see all labels in your project, you could use TFS Sidekick, which has a search for labels too. If you want to use the information in an automated process, I think there is no other option than using the api in your own small tool.